# c# How can i order a string?

Tags: c#, string, sorting

I have a string ( stringMess), where i save the time of reaction ( how long you need to click on buttons) in a string. now i want to get the fastest and lowest time in a label out, so i have to sort the string. but how can i do that? ( everything i have done until gave me an error :( )

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
//...
int Zeit = 0;
string Mess;
int Anzahl;
//...

private void btnRot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // a timer starts and when you click on the button,
   // the timer stops and write  the time in the stringMess
    Mess = Mess + Zeit + " , ";
    Anzahl = Anzahl + 1;
   //...
}
```

the code isn't the whole one...

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "sort the string". Typically you sort a *collection* with multiple values in it. It sounds like you probably shouldn't be storing all your data in a single string value...

Comment: I think he might mean that he's storing reaction times as a collection in a string and wants to parse it/reorder it based on lowest times or something.

Comment: I agree with Jon, but also I think you should be storing reaction times as a number and sorting those numbers. You should only convert the times to a string when you want to display it to the user. You're mixing up the data you're storing with how you are displaying it to the user, which is not good.

Comment: @JonLaMarr even if this is the case it's still the wrong answer. Why not just store a list of timespans?

Comment: Why store reaction times in a string when there is a perfectly good `TimeSpan` class for storing time intervals? Use a `List<TimeSpan>` instead.

Comment: i only store the time ( how long you need to click the button) in the string. and i want to sort it, so the fastetst one is the first in string...

Comment: @Franz: You are making the problem much harder by using strings. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @AMR There's no way I was saying this was the correct way to do it. Was just trying to make his problem more clear, regardless of what it is.

Comment: and how can i sort the timespan list?

Comment: It's really funny that the variable name is "Mess".  Pretty sure in German it stands for "Measured", but in English it means "a situation or state of affairs that is confused or full of difficulties".  Haha!

Answer (score 2):

You are just making the problem more difficult by using strings (and a single string at that). Use a `List` of `TimeSpan`. Something like this:

```
List<TimeSpan> reactionTimes = new List<TimeSpan>;
```

Now when you start your timer, you can do something like this:

```
startTime = DateTime.Now;
```

And when you stop:

```
reactionTimes.Add(DateTime.Now - startTime);    // Note: subtracting two DateTimes results in a TimeSpan
```

And you can sort them trivially:

```
reactionTimes.Sort();
```

Only convert them to a string when you want to display them to the user. Which is pretty simple, depending on exactly how you want them displayed (milliseconds? seconds? weeks? years?) as `TimeSpan` has a `.ToString` method that takes a format string. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx

as well as properties for `TotalMilliseconds`, `TotalSeconds`, etc that are `double`s and can be formatted however you wish.

You could probably even do (untested code):

```
string myString = string.Join(",",
    reactionTimes.Select(x => x.TotalMilliseconds.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: I think the line "reactionTimes = DateTime.Now - startTime;" should be "reactionTimes.Add(DateTime.Now - startTime);" so that you add to a collection.

Comment: I would use a Stopwatch() personally...then you can use Reset(), Start(), Stop() and Elapsed().

Comment: @RickDavin: Whoops. Brainfart. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @Idle_Mind: Stopwatch would be good to. The right choice probably depends on how large your time intervals are going to be and how accurately you need to measure them.

Comment: my time periods are very small ( <1s)... tomorrow i will test this :) thanks a lot!

Comment: @Franz: Also bear in mind that Windows is **not** a real-time operating system. There is a limit to the precision that you can get from any of these methods (and depending on the hardware you use) so you may need to play around with it some to decide whether or not you are getting the precision you need. If not, you'll need some kind of specialized hardware with a high-precision timer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want, instead of a string at all, is a collection of ints (array, list, whatever).  If you absolutely MUST have a string (homework assignment?  really, REALLY weird requirement?) you'll need to split the the string.

The first of those would look like this:

```
int Zeit = 0;
List<int> Mess = new List<int>();
int Anzahl;
```

Then your button would do this:

```
private void btnRot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //your other stuff here
  Mess.Add(Zeit);
  Anzahl++;
}
```

Then you'd get your largest and smallest values like this:

```
var biggestZeit = Mess.Max();
var littlestZeit = Mess.Min();
```

If you MUST use the string, you can still get the array (or list) of ints by doing this:

```
var resultList = Mess.Split(',').ToList();
var biggestZeit = resultList.Max(s => int.Parse(s));
var littlestZeit = resultList.Min(s => int.Parse(s));
```

As Matt points out- you could further simplify by using a collection of `TimeSpan`.